# SQL ошибка входа пользователя при попытки подключится с одного сервера на другой

Tags: ssms

Имею в своем распоряжении два сервер **A** и **B**. Имею права для чтения на обоих сервера как (Domain\User.Name). При чтении таблиц индивидуально, то есть 
`Select * From A` или `Select * From B` (не смотрите на синтаксис, это просто пример), я получаю данные без проблем. Когда же я хочу с сервера **A** прочитать что на сервере **B** получаю ошибку

```
Message 18456, level 14, status 1, line 1
Logon failed for user 'NT-AUTORITY \ ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

Если ли какие-то специальные настройки для того, чтобы все это заработало или что нужно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мб:

`Login failed for user ’NT AUTHORITY\система’`. Причина: не удалось открыть явно указанную базу данных.

**Причина**: Авторизация верная, запуск происходит с правами администратора, но база данных недоступна (или нет разрешения).

**Решение**: Группе `NT AUTHORITY\система` необходимо добавить роль `sysadmin` на `SQL` сервере. Для этого зайдите `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`, раздел Безопасность – Имена входа и выберите свойства группы `NT AUTHORITY\система`. В меню Роли сервера установите флажок напротив роли `sysadmin`.